# Morphism of affine varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I'm confused by the following thing I'm reading on the Wikipedia page [Affine variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_variety):

> Let $X = \operatorname{spec} A$, $Y = \operatorname{spec} B$ where $A$, $B$
>   are integral domains that are the quotient of the polynomial ring
>   $k[t_1, \dots, t_n]$, k an algebraically closed field.
>
> A morphism of affine varieties: Each $k$-algebra homomorphism $\phi: B \to A$
>   defines the continuous function $\phi^{\# }:X \to Y$ by
>   $\mathfrak{m} \mapsto \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{m}$).

But isn't it the case that unless $\phi$ is surjective, $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})$ needs not be an ideal in $B$?

Comment: What makes you think that? If $x \in \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak m)$, then $\phi(xy) =\phi(x) \phi(y) \in \mathfrak m$ for all $y$.

Comment: The preimage is always an ideal, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409999/prove-that-the-preimage-of-a-prime-ideal-is-also-prime).

Comment: Oops, silly me (: Thanks!