# Prove that $I=\{r \in R: f(r) \in J\}$ is a prime ideal in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $f:R\to S$ be a surjective homomorphism of commutative rings. If $J$ is a prime ideal in $S$, and $I=\{r \in R: f(r) \in J\}$, prove that $I$ is a prime ideal in $R$.

I am perfectly fine with proving that $I$ is prime, however, I am struggling to prove that $I$ is an ideal in $R$ in the first place.

Clearly $I \neq \emptyset$, since if $j \in J\subseteq S$, by surjectivity of $f$, there exists an $r \in R$ s.t. $f(r)=j$, i.e. $r \in I$.

Now let $a,b \in I$, then $f(a), f(b) \in J$. Then $f(ab)=f(a)f(b) \in J$, i.e. $ab \in I$.

Also notice that $f(a-b)=f(a)-f(b) \in J$ (since $J$ is an ideal, and hence a subring, of $S$), and so $a-b \in I$.

We thus have that $I$ is a subring of $R$. In order to prove that $I$ is an ideal in $R$, we require the following

> If $a \in I$ and $r \in R$, then $ar \in I$. Since $I$ is commutative (since $R$ is commutative), this will be enough to ensure that $ra=ar \in I$ is also satisfied.

This is the part I am struggling with:

Let $a \in I$, then $f(a) \in J$.Now consider any $r \in R$, then clearly $f(r) \in S$ and so $f(ar)=f(a)f(r) \in S$. The problem, however, is I require $f(ar) \in J$ to have that $ar \in I$.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409999/prove-that-the-preimage-of-a-prime-ideal-is-also-prime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Since $J$ is an ideal, for any $f(r) \in J$ and $f(a)\in S$
$$
f(ar)=f(a)f(r) \in J
$$

Comment: That makes sense. But should it not hold for **any** $r \in R$? We're not guaranteed that, for any $r \in R$, $f(r) \in J$, are we - since $f:R \to S$, and so $f(r)$ is not necessarily in $J$? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way? :)

Comment: It is true that for any $r\in R\:, f(r)\in S$

Comment: Thank you! It makes perfect sense to me now! :)

Comment: I don't understand: this should not require surjectivity, and it doesn't like you really used it in your proof.  Given $a \in I$ and $r \in R$, then $f(a) \in J$ so $f(ra) = f(r) f(a) \in J$, and hence $ra \in I$.  The inverse image of a prime ideal is a prime ideal under any homomorphism, surjective or not.