# Contraction of a prime ideal in the localization of $R$ relative to $S.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that if $J$ is a prime ideal of $S^{-1}R,$ then the contraction $J^c$ via a fixed homomorphism $\phi: R \rightarrow S^{-1}R$ is also a prime ideal of $R.$ But first I want to show that $R/J^c$ is a subring of $S^{-1}R/J.$ The way I do this is, is by showing that we have a natural homomorphism $\phi': R \rightarrow S^{-1}R/J.$ Then, we have that the kernel of the map is $J^c.$ Hence, $R/J^c$ is isomorphic to the image of $R$ which is a subring of $S^{-1}R/J.$ Is my idea correct?

Showing this, I say that $R/J^c$ is a subring of a domain so must be a domain itself and hence, $J^c$ must be prime.

Comment: Your approach seems correct.  Just as a note, this is true in general, not just for the localization homomorphism.  If $A$ and $B$ are commutative rings, $\varphi: A \to B$ is a ring homomorphism, and $P$ is a prime ideal of $B$, then $\varphi^{-1}(P)$ is a prime ideal of $A$.  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409999/prove-that-the-preimage-of-a-prime-ideal-is-also-prime).