# If $Q$ is a prime ideal in $S$ , then $f^{-1}(Q)$ is a prime ideal in $R$ that contains $K.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $f:R\longrightarrow S$ be an epimorphism of rings with kernel $K.$
>
> If $Q$ is a prime ideal in $S$ , then $f^{-1}(Q)$ is a prime ideal in $R$ that contains $K.$

Now I know how to show $f^{-1}(Q)$ is an ideal that contains the kernel $K$, I just not very sure the part of prime ideal . So I show this part as follows .

**Here's my attempt :(I edited)**

Given $AB\subseteq f^{-1}(Q)$ for any ideals $A,B$ in $R$ .

Hence , $f(A)f(B)=f(AB)\subseteq f\big(f^{-1}(Q)\big)=Q,$ where the first equality holds by the very definition of the multiplication of ideals and the second equality is according to the surjectivity of $f$.

But $Q$ is a prime ideal in $S$ . Thus we have $f(A)\subseteq Q$ or $f(B)\subseteq Q .$

If $f(A)\subseteq Q$ , then $f(x)\in f(A)\subseteq Q$ for all $x\in A$ and hence $x\in f^{-1}(Q)$ for each $x\in A$ so $A\subseteq f^{-1} (Q)$ , otherwise if $f(B)\subseteq Q$ we can deduce that $B\subseteq f^{-1}(Q)$ by a similar way as previuos . Therefore , $f^{-1}(Q)$ is actually a prime ideal in $R$ .

Comment: By considering ideals $A$ and $B$, you are making things hard for yourself. An ideal $I$ is prime if $ab\in I$ implies $a\in I$ or $b\in I$. Alternatively, $I$ is prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain.

Comment: I wonder if the following reasoning is valid: $R/K\cong S$ and $f^{-1}(Q)/K\cong Q$ and $R/f^{-1}(Q)\cong(R/K)/(f^{-1}(Q)/K)$, so $R/f^{-1}(Q)\cong S/Q$, as $S/Q$ is an integral domain, then so is $R/f^{-1}(Q)$, so $f^{-1}(Q)$ is prime.

Comment: $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$, really? This holds when $f$ is injective, but epi means surjective as I know.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown :Thanks for your commend. I think the well -
 known fact : $I$ is prime iff $R/I$ is a integral domain is true provided the ring $R$ is commutative with identity $1_{R} \ne 0$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409999/prove-that-the-preimage-of-a-prime-ideal-is-also-prime

Comment: @AreaMan : Thanks for supplying . But here we do not restrict the rings $R$ and $S$ being commutative .