# Inverse image of a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am having trouble understanding how the map on prime ideals induced by a ring homomorphism works. For instance, given a homomorphism $\phi:R\rightarrow R[x]$, we get an induced map $\phi^*:\operatorname{Spec}R[x]\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} R$ given by $\phi^*(\mathfrak{p})=\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$. Clearly for this induced map to make sense, every element of $\operatorname{Spec} R[x]$ must get mapped somewhere, but I cannot see how primes in $R$ are mapping along $\phi$. Here is a concrete example of where my understanding must be wrong: I consider $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The map is the natural embedding $m\mapsto m$ right? But then the image of the prime $(2)$ is not prime and I'm not sure if it should be. Then what are inverse images of primes like $\phi^{-1}(x-1)$ or $\phi^{-1}(x-1,3)$? What am I missing here? I know the answer is supposed to be $\phi^{-1}(x-1)=(0)$ and $\phi^{-1}(x-1,3)=(3)$; you take the intersection with prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$, I just don't see why.

Comment: This question is kind of going in the wrong direction: there's no reason for the image of a prime ideal to be prime. On the other hand, [the inverse image of a prime ideal is always prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409999/). So all you need to do is compute inverse images of those ideals - that means finding all the elements in the ideal which are the image of some element of $\Bbb Z$, aka finding all the integers in those ideals since $m\mapsto m$ as you say. (Also, please use `$\operatorname{Spec}$` to format $\operatorname{Spec}$.)

Comment: (to add to @KReiser's comment, I'd also point out that there's no reason for the image of an ideal under a ring homomorphism to even be an ideal! for example, in the example you use, the image of a ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ under the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}[x]$ will not even be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ unless $I$ is the zero ideal)